# Chack miy spellang pleez

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, homework, set

For my CS2 project, I am supposed to implement a spell-checker.  It is
supposed to follow the following:

> 1. Prompt the user for the name of the file containing the dictionary
>      of    correctly spelled words
> 2. Read in the name of their dictionary file
> 3. Open an input file stream on their filename
> 4. If their filename successfully opens:
>
>    1. For each word in the dictionary file:
>
>       - Add the word to the `dictionary` `LinkedSet`
>    2. Close the dictionary file
> 5. Do while the user wants to spell check files:
>      Prompt the user for the name of a file to spell check
>
>    1. Read in the name of their file
>    2. Open an input file stream on their file
>    3. If the file successfully opens
>
>       1. For each word in their file:
>
>          - Clean the word of extraneous characters
>          - Convert the word to lowercase
>          - Add the word to the `fileBeingSpellChecked` `LinkedSet`
>       2. Close the file being spell checked
>    4. Create a `LinkedSet` on the difference of the `fileBeingSpellChecked`
>         and the dictionary
>    5. Display the contents of the difference `LinkedSet`
>    6. Clear the `fileBeingSpellChecked` `LinkedSet`
>    7. Clear the difference `LinkedSet`
>    8. Prompt the user whether they want to spell check another file
>    9. Get their response
> 6. Quit

***Warning***: there is a lot of code below, if reviewers don't want to go through all of the other code, please just focus on my `main.cpp` file.

---

**`SetInterface.h`**:

```
#ifndef SET_INTERFACE
#define SET_INTERFACE

#include <vector>

/** @class SetInterface SetInterface.h "SetInterface.h"
 *
 *  Definition of SetInterface class template. 
 */
template <typename T>
class SetInterface 
{
public:

  /** Virtual destructor. */
  virtual ~SetInterface() {}

  /** Gets the current number of entries in this set.
   *  @return The integer number of entries currently in the set. 
   */
  virtual int size() const = 0;

  /** Sees whether this set is empty.
   *
   *  @return True if the set is empty, or false if not. 
   */
  virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

  /** Adds a new entry to this set.
   *
   *  @post If successful and unique, newEntry is stored in the set and the
   *        count of items in the set has increased by 1.
   *
   *  @param newEntry The object to be added as a new entry.
   *
   *  @return True if addition was successful and unique, or false if not. 
   */
  virtual bool add(const T&) = 0;

  /** Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this set, if
   *  possible.
   *
   *  @post If successful, anEntry has been removed from the set and
   *        the count of items in the set has decreased by 1.
   *
   *  @param anEntry The value of the entry to be removed.
   *
   *  @return True if removal was successful, or false if not. 
   */
  virtual bool remove(const T&) = 0;

  /** Removes all entries from this set.
   *
   *  @post This set contains no items (thus the count is 0). 
   */
  virtual void clear() = 0;

  /** Counts the number of times a given entry appears in set.
   *
   *  @param anEntry The value of the entry to be counted.
   *
   *  @return The number of times anEntry appears in this set. 
   */
  virtual int count(const T&) const = 0;

  /** Tests whether this set contains a given entry.
   *
   *  @param anEntry The value of the entry to locate.
   *
   *  @return True if this set contains anEntry, or false
   *          otherwise. 
   */
  virtual bool contains(const T&) const = 0;

  /** Converts this set into a vector.
   *
   *  @return A vector containing all the entries in this set. 
   */
  virtual std::vector<T> toVector() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

**`Node.h`**:

```
#ifndef NODE
#define NODE

template <typename T>
class Node {
 private:
  T item;
  Node<T>* next;

 public:
  Node();
  Node(const T& anItem);
  Node(const T& anItem,
       Node<T>* nextNodePtr);

  void setItem(const T& anItem);
  void setNext(Node<T>* nextNodePtr);

  T getItem() const;
  Node<T>* getNext() const;
};

#include "Node.cpp"

#endif
```

**`Node.cpp`**:

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node()
  : next(nullptr) {
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& anItem)
  : item(anItem),
    next(nullptr) {
    }

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& anItem,
                     Node<T>* nextNodePtr)
  : item(anItem),
    next(nextNodePtr) {
    }

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setItem(const T& anItem) {

  item = anItem;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setNext(Node<T>* nextNodePtr) {

  next = nextNodePtr;
}

template <typename T>
T Node<T>::getItem() const {

  return item;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::getNext() const {

  return next;
}
```

**`LinkedSet.h`**:

```
#ifndef LINKED_SET
#define LINKED_SET

#include "SetInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"

/** @class LinkedBag LinkedBag.h "LinkedBag.h"
 *
 *  Specification of a pointer-based ADT set. */
template <typename T>
class LinkedSet : public SetInterface<T> 
{
private:
  /** Pointer to first node. */
  Node<T>* headPtr;

  /** Number of items in this bag. */
  int itemCount;

  /** Gets a pointer to the node containing the target in this bag.
   *
   * @pre None.
   *
   * @post None.
   *
   * @param target The T value to find.
   *
   * @return A pointer to the node that contains the given target or
   *         nullptr if the bag does not contain the target. 
   */
    Node<T>* getPointerTo(const T& target) const;
public:
    LinkedSet();
    LinkedSet(const LinkedSet<T>& aSet);
    virtual ~LinkedSet();
    Node<T>* getHeadPtr();
    int size() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    virtual bool add(const T& newEntry);
    virtual bool remove(const T& anEntry);
    virtual LinkedSet<T> difference(LinkedSet<T>&);
    virtual void clear();
    virtual int count(const T& anEntry) const;
    virtual bool contains(const T& anEntry) const;
    virtual std::vector<T> toVector() const;
};

#include "LinkedSet.cpp"

#endif
```

**`LinkedSet.cpp`**:

```
template <typename T>
LinkedSet<T>::LinkedSet() : headPtr(nullptr), itemCount(0) {}

template <typename T>
LinkedSet<T>::LinkedSet(const LinkedSet<T>& aBag) 
{
  itemCount = aBag.itemCount;

  if (aBag.headPtr == nullptr) {
    headPtr = nullptr;
  }
  else {
    Node<T>* origChainPtr = aBag.headPtr;

    headPtr = new Node<T>();
    headPtr->setItem(origChainPtr->getItem() );

    Node<T>* newChainPtr = headPtr;

    origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();

    while (origChainPtr != nullptr) {
      T nextItem = origChainPtr->getItem();

      Node<T>* newNodePtr = new Node<T>(nextItem);

      newChainPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);

      newChainPtr = newChainPtr->getNext();

      origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();
    }

    newChainPtr->setNext(nullptr);
  }
}

template <typename T>
LinkedSet<T>::~LinkedSet() 
{
  clear();
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* LinkedSet<T>::getHeadPtr()
{
  return headPtr;
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedSet<T>::size() const 
{
  return itemCount;
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedSet<T>::isEmpty() const 
{
  return 0 == itemCount;
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedSet<T>::add(const T& newEntry) 
{
  if (contains(newEntry)) return false; 
  else
  {
      Node<T>* newNodePtr = new Node<T>();
      newNodePtr->setItem(newEntry);
      newNodePtr->setNext(headPtr);
      headPtr = newNodePtr;

      ++itemCount;
      return true;
  }
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedSet<T>::remove(const T& anEntry) 
{
  bool canRemoveItem = !isEmpty();

  if (canRemoveItem) {
    Node<T>* entryNodePtr = getPointerTo(anEntry);

    canRemoveItem = entryNodePtr != nullptr;

    if (canRemoveItem) {
      entryNodePtr->setItem(headPtr->getItem()); 
      Node<T>* nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;
      headPtr = headPtr->getNext();

      nodeToDeletePtr->setNext(nullptr);
      delete nodeToDeletePtr;
      nodeToDeletePtr = nullptr;

      --itemCount;
    }
  }

  return canRemoveItem;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedSet<T> LinkedSet<T>::difference(LinkedSet<T>& linkedSet)
{
    LinkedSet<T> newLinkedSet;
    //Node<T> *ptr1, *ptr2;

    //for(ptr1 = headPtr; ptr1; ptr1 = ptr1->getNext())
    //{
    //for(ptr2 = linkedSet.getHeadPtr(); ptr2; ptr2 = ptr2->getNext())
    //  {
    //      if(ptr1->getItem() == ptr2->getItem()) break;
    //      if(ptr2->getNext() == nullptr) newLinkedSet.add(ptr1->getItem());
    //  }
    //}

    std::vector<T> vec1 = toVector();
    std::vector<T> vec2 = linkedSet.toVector();

    for(int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < vec2.size(); ++j)
        {
          if(vec1.at(i) == vec2.at(j)) break;
          if(j == vec2.size() - 1) 
        {
          newLinkedSet.add(vec1.at(i));
        }       
    }
    }

    return newLinkedSet;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedSet<T>::clear() {

  Node<T>* nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;

  while (headPtr != nullptr) {
    headPtr = headPtr->getNext();

    nodeToDeletePtr->setNext(nullptr);
    delete nodeToDeletePtr;

    nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;
  }
  // headPtr is nullptr; nodeToDeletePtr is nullptr.

  itemCount = 0;
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedSet<T>::contains(const T& anEntry) const 
{
  return getPointerTo(anEntry) != nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedSet<T>::count(const T& anEntry) const 
{
  int frequency = 0;

  Node<T>* curPtr = headPtr;

  while (curPtr != nullptr) {
    if (curPtr->getItem() == anEntry) {
      ++frequency;
    }

    curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
  }

  return frequency;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> LinkedSet<T>::toVector() const {

  std::vector<T> bagContents;

  Node<T>* curPtr = headPtr;

  while (curPtr != nullptr) {
    bagContents.push_back(curPtr->getItem() );

    curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
  }

  return bagContents;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* LinkedSet<T>::getPointerTo(const T& target) const {

  bool found = false;

  Node<T>* curPtr = headPtr;

  while (!found && curPtr != nullptr) {
    if (curPtr->getItem() == target) {
      found = true;
    }
    else {
      curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
    }
  }

  return curPtr;
}
```

**`main.cpp`**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "LinkedSet.h"

char getSanitizedChar()
{
  // absorb newline character (if existant) from previous input
  if('\n' == std::cin.peek()) std::cin.ignore();
  return std::tolower(std::cin.get());
}

std::string cleanString(std::string str)
{
    std::string remove = "!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]:;\"\'`<>,.?/|\\"; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < remove.length(); ++i)
    {
        str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), remove.at(i)), str.end());
    }
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
    return str;
}

template <typename T>
void displaySet(LinkedSet<T> set)
{
    std::vector<T> vec = set.toVector();
    std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vec.at(i) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{    
    LinkedSet<std::string> dictionary;
    LinkedSet<std::string> fileBeingChecked;
    std::string defaultDict = "../small.dat";  //"/usr/share/dict/american-english";
    std::string dictFilename;
    std::string line;

    std::cout << "Enter name of dictionary file (press <ENTER> for default): ";
    std::getline(std::cin, dictFilename);
    std::ifstream dict(dictFilename.length() ? dictFilename : defaultDict);
    if(dict.good())
    {
        std::cout << "Loading file contents..." << std::endl;
        while(std::getline(dict, line))
        {
            std::string word;
            std::istringstream lineStream(line);
            while(lineStream >> word)
            {
                dictionary.add(word);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening dictionary file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    dict.close();

    std::string checkFilename;
    std::string defaultCheck = "../small.txt";
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the name of a file to spell check (press <ENTER> for default): ";
        std::getline(std::cin, checkFilename);
        std::ifstream check(checkFilename.length() ? checkFilename : defaultCheck);
        if (check.good())
        {
            while(std::getline(check, line))
            {
                std::string word;
                std::istringstream lineStream(line);
                while(lineStream >> word)
                {
                    word = cleanString(word);
                    fileBeingChecked.add(word);
                }
            }
            std::cout << fileBeingChecked.size() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error opening file to check." << std::endl;
        }
        check.close();

        LinkedSet<std::string> diff(fileBeingChecked.difference(dictionary));
        displaySet(diff);
        fileBeingChecked.clear();

        std::cout << "Check another file (y/N)? ";
    } while('y' == getSanitizedChar());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (if existant)

Spellin errah!

- `void displaySet(LinkedSet<T> set)` wants to be

  ```
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const LinkedSet<T>&);
  ```

  Along the same line I would argue that

  ```
      while(lineStream >> word)
      {
          dictionary.add(word);
      }
  ```

  is

  ```
  std::istream operator>>(std::istream, LinkedSet<T>&)
  ```

  in disguise.
- `difference` is suboptimal. If it is OK to convert `LinkedSet`s to `vector`s, it is surely OK to sort the vectors.